# How do I define and view a scripted_field in my Kibana 3 dashboard?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have Kibana 3 connected to ElasticSearch. I can successfully query and view data, and create custom dashboards. However, I can't get any scripted field to display in my dashboard.

1. Where should the scripted field be defined in the dashboard? I tried putting this in a few places in my dashboard:

script_fields" : {
            "test" : {
              "script" : "testing"
            }
          }

2. How should I refer to a scripted field in the dashboard? ie, to display a normal returned field, I use rows.panels.fields = @fields.myfieldname. I've tried @fields.test and @script_fields.test and a few others with no result.
3. Do I need to go to Kibana 4 to realize this functionality?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 0):

You cannot define the scripted fields in a Kibana 3 dashboard. You could predefine your script in your Elasticsearch settings and then query for the scripted field name as a normal fiel, in your case "test".

Kibana 4 will let you define scripted fields on the fly.

Comment: OK, I'm trying out Kibana 4 and I can specify a scripted field from settings, but only numerical fields. Is there a way to specify a script that returns a string? And how do I do this on the fly in a dashboard?